# Formal proofs and Deduction Theorem

Tags: logic, proof-theory

In this question i will explain one idea i had about basic formal proofs and the use of Deduction Theorem.

I'm considering a formula γ to be a logical consequence of a set A of formulas if and only if it is true in all models of the set A of formulas ( structures that satisfy the set of A formulas ).
Also, I'm considering a formal proof of a formula γ from a set A of formulas, as a finite list of formulas that are either formulas of A, logically valid formulas ( instances of axioms schemmas ) or formulas obtained by applying rules of infernece ( axiom schemmas ) to two or more preeceding formulas on the list.

At the same time, by soundness, to say that we have a formal proof of γ from the set A, would be saying that :
$ A⊨γ  $

Now i have a series of questions...

First of, is it it true that for all propositions(theorems,etc) that simply affirm that a formula is a logical consequence of a set of formulas, no matter how hard(long) its ( of proposition ) formal proof is, will it always possibly be represented by a long chain of "logical consequences" ?
I heard from a lecturer say that this would be the most "formal" kind of formal proof, a formal proof consisting only of a chain of logical consequences.
For example, for any A,γ , is it possible to represent the formal proof of γ from A as :

$ A \\
⊨β1\\⊨β2\\...\\⊨γ $

If the answer is yes, then i imediately thought that we could use deduction theorem to transform it into the following logically valid formula :

$A→(β1→(β2→(....→γ)))$

So, i thought that it would mean that actually any formal proof in this more formal state ( only chains of logical consequences) could be seen as possibly translated to a logically valid formula of our formal logic ( first-order, second-order ... ) that has the form of an implication, and that has all information required and used to prove γ from A.
Is it true ?
Let me give one example :

http://postimg.org/image/fcg318fsn/

Extrapolation, ignore if completely wrong

As an analogy i thought of the tuple (4,3,2) in R^n that carries all information needed about the polynomial 4x² + 3x + 2 .

So , analogally, could we view a kind of "informal isomorphism" between the set of all formal proofs in that "supposedly rigorous" state of only chain of logical consequences and logically valid formulas of our formal language in that shape ( chain of implications ) ?

Then it would be possible to translate back and forth between formal proofs on that state, and logically valid implications of our formal language.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Note that [you can use $\LaTeX$ syntax here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math, which would be easier to read than your current formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deduction theorem says if {$\gamma$, $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\beta$, then $\gamma$ $\vdash$ ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$).  Now you can represent a proof of $\gamma$ from $\alpha$ by a sequence

$\alpha$

$\vdash$ $\beta$1

$\vdash$ $\beta$2

.

.

.

$\vdash$ $\gamma$.

Consequently by the deduction theorem we can obtain ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\alpha$), ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta1$), ..., ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$).  I repeat for emphasis that we have ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$) by having the deduction theorem.  Now there exists a theorem which says:

((p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$(p$\rightarrow$(r$\rightarrow$q))).

Thus to obtain ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\beta$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$)) we substitute p with $\alpha$, q with $\gamma$, and r with $\beta$ in ((p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$(p$\rightarrow$(r$\rightarrow$q))), and from ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$) we detach ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\beta$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$)).

We iterate this process, substituting p with $\alpha$, q with ($\beta$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$), and r with $\delta$, and then we can detach
($\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\delta$$\rightarrow$($\beta$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$))).

The catch here comes as that we should obtain ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\beta$$_n$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$)) first, then ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\beta$$_m$$\rightarrow$($\beta$$_n$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$)) next [where "m"=(n-1)], until we finally obtain ($\alpha$→(β1→(β2→(....→γ)))).

Now let's suppose that we have ($\alpha$→(β1→(β2→(....→γ)))), and $\alpha$.  By detachment we can obtain (β1→(β2→(....→γ))).  Thus, if we have ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$1) also, we can obtain $\beta$1 and thus (β2→(....→γ)).  Eventually we can obtain ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\gamma$).

So, the answer to your question, I think, is "yes".

But, notice that the deduction theorem itself doesn't directly give us such a transformation as your original post suggests.  We used

((p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$(p$\rightarrow$(r$\rightarrow$q))) for this to work.

That said, if we have the deduction theorem, then ((p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$(p$\rightarrow$(r$\rightarrow$q))) will follow, as we can see from the following:

```
hypothesis          1 | (p→q)
hypothesis          2 || p
hypothesis          3 ||| r
detachment 1, 2     4 ||| q
conditional-in 3-4  5 || (r→q)
conditional-in 2-5  6 | (p→(r→q))
conditional-in 1-6  7 ((p→q)→(p→(r→q)))
```

If we have {(p→(q→p)), ((p→(q→r))→((p→q)→(p→r)))} as the basis used for proving the deduction theorem (other bases exist) we could also prove ((p→q)→(p→(r→q))) as follows:

```
axiom               1 (p→(q→p))
axiom               2 ((p→(q→r))→((p→q)→(p→r)))
1 p/q, q/r          3 (q→(r→q))
1 p/(q→(r→q)), q/p  4 ((q→(r→q))→(p→(q→(r→q))))
detachment 4, 3     5 (p→(q→(r→q)))
2 r/(r→q)           6 ((p→(q→(r→q)))→((p→q)→(p→(r→q))))
detachment 6, 5     7 ((p→q)→(p→(r→q))))
```

If we ignore the substitutions here, it looks like in this case that an axiomatic proof can work out as shorter than a natural deduction derivation.

Comment: Thanks for answering the second part of the question, it was made clear. But would you know the first part too ?

Comment: is it it true that for all propositions(theorems,etc) that simply affirm that a formula is a logical consequence of a set of formulas, no matter how hard(long) its ( of proposition ) formal proof is, will it always possibly be represented by a long chain of "logical consequences" ? I heard from a lecturer say that this would be the most "formal" kind of formal proof, a formal proof consisting only of a chain of logical consequences.For example,for any A,γ , is it always possible to represent the formal proof of γ from A as :  $\\ A \\ \models \beta1  \\ \models \beta2 \\ ... \\ \models \gamma$

Comment: @nerdy Can you represent the last proof I've put in my answer by that format?  Well, it has two axioms used, which consequently need stated for the sequence to qualify as a formal proof.  The axioms are independent of each other in that neither axiom can derive the other (under uniform substitution and detachment).  So, given a basis with more than one element (axiom) the answer is no.  However, for many logical systems there exists a basis consisting of a single element.  In other words, the single axiom {A} for the system can derive the axioms in {B, ... Bn}} of another given basis, and 1/2

Comment: @nerdy {B, ..., Bn} can derive A (under the same set of inference rules... usually uniform substitution and detachment).  For example, the two axiom basis I used above {(p→(q→p)), ((p→(q→r))→((p→q)→(p→r)))} could get replaced by any of the 12, 17-letter single axioms here http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~dulrich/C-pure-intuitionism-page.htm  If we do that, then we could write a proof of "((p→q)→(p→(r→q))))" or equivalently "CCpqCpCrq" in Polish notation, in the format you've suggested... except that we wouldn't use the semantic turnstile indicator |=, we'd use |- or omit it.

Comment: Couldn't we entirely represent your ( axiomatic )  proof as this chain of logical consequences ?    http://postimg.org/image/jit7s9izn/

Comment: @nerdy No.  There is no connective "$\land$" in the proof I've used.  The proof I've used will work for a subsystem of classical logic, which *only* has "→" as a connective.  Your proof won't work for that system.  Also, you can't define "$\land$" using just "→".  Each time you introduce a conjunction there you've used the rule {$\alpha$, $\beta$} $\vdash$ ($\alpha$ $\land$ $\beta$).  It's not derivable as a rule when you don't have a $\land$ connective, nor when ($\alpha$$\land$$\beta$) doesn't serve as a shorthand for some other expression (which relies on inter-definability of connectives).

Comment: I have two questions.  1 -  What would be the use of a subsystem of classical logic which only has "$->$" in the logical signature ? Wouldn't it have an incomplete logical signature ?    2-  Would then be only a matter of allowing the common $\wedge$ connective in order to possibly represent the formal proof of any propositions(theorems,etc) that simply affirm that a formula is a logical consequence of a set of formulas, as a long chain of logical consequences ?

Comment: @Nerdy A subsystem of classical logic which only has "−>" can tell us what we can deduce solely from a set of implicational axioms (under a given set of rules).  It can reveal connections between different sets of formulas.  It can also potentially produce shorter, or maybe more clear or intuitive, proofs than proofs which use other connectives. For instance, one could prove the theorem CCCpqrCCrpp by assuming the negation of p, 1 "Np", 2 assuming p, 3 assumping Nq, 4 discharging q since have a contradiction, inferring 5 Cpq, then 6 r, then 7 p and then having a contradiction we obtain 8 p 1/2

Comment: On the other hand, if we have CCCpqpp as an axiom or theorem, we can assume 1 Cpq, deduce 2 r, then 3 p, then infer 4 CCpqp, and then by CCCpqpp obtain 5 p.  Consequently, studying such a subsystem can prove useful in finding shorter proofs.  It also can come as easier to resolve metalogical questions like that of completeness, or what is the shortest axiom of a system for some subsystems... e.g. the shortest axioms of the classical equivalential propositional calculus and the classical implicational propositional calculus have gotten found, but we don't know about conditional-negation logic.

Comment: continued... I don't know what you mean by "incomplete logical signature".  The term "completeness" often refers to the intended semantics of a system.  If the intended semantics comes as that of intuitionistic implication, the above two formulas "CpCqp" and "CCpCqrCCpqCpr" (under substitution and detachment) qualify as complete.  If the intended semantics comes as all implications which qualify as tautologies in {T, F}, CCCpqrCCrpCsp suffices as an axiom.  With respect to your second question the proofs in my answer (though not in the comments) give us formal proofs of propositions that ...

Comment: simply affirm that a formula is a logical consequence of a *set* of formulas, as a long chain of logical consequences of that *set* of formulas.  However, they do NOT give a proof from a single formula as your original post seemed to me to suggest.  If you allow a $\land$ connective in though, you end up talking about a different kind of system.  If you only want $\land$ for the purpose you've suggested, the idea involved involves a different notion of conjunction than that of classical logic (or intuitionistic or mulit-valued logic for that matter).

Comment: You talked about the conditional-negation logic, there we could define the and i used on the proof as a $\wedge$ b = $\neg(a \to \neg b) $. So would it be far to say at least in a subsystem with either negation/conjunction, negation/implication or negation/disjunction  could we indeed see all formal proofs propositions that simply affirm that a formula is a logical consequence of a set of formulas as a chain of logical consequences from a single formula ?

Comment: @nerdy The answer to your question is not always.  If we have a system with only one axiom, then all formal proofs affirm (or imply if we use derived rules, since they don't allow any formulas into the system which could not get derived using just the primitive rules of the system) that a formula is a logical consequence of that single axiom.  Oftentimes when we have an axiom set with more than one element, an axiom set with a single element can get found (the systems we've referenced have single axioms, with the *possible* exception of the negation/implication system).  But...

Comment: proofs like the one I put in this answer are not consequences from a single formula.  The proof I wrote had two axioms.  The set of those axioms under detachment and uniform substitution has the same set of theorems as several systems with a single axiom under the same rules.  However, the formal proof itself consists of the actually *written* sequence of formulas.  It doesn't start with a single formula taken as an axiom, but rather two axioms.  So if you did view it as the consequence from a single formula, you would have to ignore the two axioms you saw to start the proof.

Comment: Hm, actually i'm not talking about formal proofs of formulas in sense they they can be derivable from the axioms in our system, i'm talking about more like formal deduction of formulas from set of formulas.What i'm thinking is that if we are going to show a formal deduction of $\alpha_1 , \alpha_2 , ... \alpha_n \models \gamma $ then provided we are working in a system w/ negation/implication, we are always going to be able to start at the single formula $\alpha_1 \wedge \alpha_2 \wedge ... \wedge \alpha_n $ and go using our rules of inference (in our sub system ) one by one to reach $\gamma$.

Comment: I think this was the main thing i wrote wrong.While i was talking about a formal proof of $A \models \gamma$ consisting only of a chain of logical consequences, actually what i meant was not a proof from the set of axioms in our system, but actually a deduction of $\gamma$ from the set A, which can start the proof as a single formula containing all conjunctions of its inside formulas, and go deriving one new formula at a time , making a chain of logical consequences and in the end deriving $\gamma$.continued

Comment: I was interested if a formal deduction of $\gamma$ from A could always be made as a chain of logical consequences starting from the single formula represented by the conjunction of all formulas inside A, provided we are in a logic system that has conjunction as a logical connective.

Comment: I also should thank you for taking the time to help me with this :).

Comment: @nerdy So "A" represents the set of assumptions?  I'll assume that it does.  You ask "I was interested if a formal deduction of γ from A could always be made as a chain of logical consequences starting from the single formula represented by the conjunction of all formulas inside A, provided we are in a logic system that has conjunction as a logical connective."  No, because there might exist only a single formula inside gamma, in which case we can't make a conjunction (we have to have two formulas to make a conjunction of those formulas).  In classical logic instead of starting from...

Comment: multiple assumptions, for a deduction of $\gamma$ from A, you could start with either a single assumption which is not a conjunction or a conjunction (of a conjunction of a conjunction if need be) of formulas.  This has nothing to do with the deduction meta-theorem necessarily though which in effect allows us to discharge an assumption into a formula.

Comment: I was interested if a formal deduction of γ from A could always be made as a chain of logical consequences starting from the single formula represented by the conjunction of all formulas inside A, provided we are in a logic system that has conjunction as a logical connective.  Obviously if A contains only one formula, i'm talking about starting only from that formula ..

Comment: @nerdy Sure you can start with such a conjunction, and then get to the end point, so long as you have the rules K$\alpha$$\beta$ $\vdash$ $\alpha$ and K$\alpha$$\beta$ $\vdash$ $\beta$ where "K" is in Polish notation, indicating conjunction, and K precedes its arguments "$\alpha$" and "$\beta$".